# Couchdb reduce shrink rate check denies the view

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I know this has been discussed a fair amount of times but my scenario I think yells for disabling the rate limit check:

Docs are in the form:

```
{ prefix: "004945", country: "Germany", type: "Mobile", carrier: "OrangeTel", price: "34"}
{ prefix: "004946", country: "Germany", type: "Mobile", carrier: "SomeOther", price: "46"}
.
.
.
{ prefix: "00807", country: "Unknown", type: "Satelite", carrier: "Inmarsat", price: "123"}
```

Now I want to get an array of those prefixes some `[country, type, carrier]` key or a `[country, type]` key

So I map like this:

`emit( [country, type, carrier],[prefix] )`
and I reduce like this:

```
reduce: function(keys, values, rereduce) { 
           return values.reduce(function(a, b) {return a.concat(b);})
        }
```

The problem is that the shrink rate is not good enough because obviously I return the same amount of data in a different shape: I convert a list with many elements ,each with little data, to a list of few elements, each with much data.

I know I can workaround it with list functions and such, but I thing the scenario is valid for disabling the check. Also, if it exists, I would like any ideas that use a map-reduce solution without changing the structure of those docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The main task of reduce functions is to reduce result that was produced by map functions.

Since your map function emits `[prefix]` as value, `[prefix]` is different for each key and you'd like to reduce/group keys, probably you also interested to not see `[prefix]` duplicates for each group, right?

Next reduce function makes a set from values array and should produce unique and short list of `[prefix]`-es for your keys and it doesn't suffer from shirk rate problem. If you need to count how much different prefixes occurs for reduced key, this will be another function, but target is the same: reduce reduce and rereduce long list of values(:

```js
function(keys, values, rereduce){
  var prefixes = [];
  var update_set = function(src, dst){
    for (var idx in src){
      item = src[idx];
      if (dst.indexOf(item) == -1){
        dst.push(item);
      }
    }
    return dst;
  }
  if (rereduce){
    for (var idx in values){
      update_set(values[idx], prefixes);
    }
  }
  else{
    update_set(values, prefixes);
  }
  return prefixes;
}
```

Comment: I cant see though, how your reduce fun is different from mine, except from the fact that it caters for duplicates. Dont you essentially create the return value by concatenating the passed values? The shrink rate checker measures size of output so your reduce will not make things better since duplicate values for the same view key are very very rare if non existent.

Comment: You may concatenate values instead of storing them separately within array if you want, but no, this variant wouldn't failed due to shrink rate since the returned value will be at least equal initial values list, not bigger them. However, you may prove it by yourself by looking at the [source code][https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/share/server/views.js#L36] - note that result shouldn't be at least twice longer than initial values. Since `N` is all `values` items and `M` is unique `values` items, M <= N, but mostly M < N, so problem is avoided.

Comment: My [country,type,carriers] view keys are aprox. 40.000 .In them there are only 3 duplicate prefixes. Anyway I checked your function and it returns the same shrink rate error... I think the results should be at most half the size of the input not the opposite... I ll take a look at the code.

Comment: Hm..I'd tested it before post with your example data, so wounder why it fails. Could you upload sample of problem data to somewhere (iriscouch for example) to let me play with it. Just also interesting how to and why so...

Comment: I found why: in the source code you mention above, it throws the error when 2 * reduced length > input length. So essentially I should at least half the output of each reduce in order not to throw a shrink rate error.

Comment: Ooops, I see my mistake and you're correct about result length restrictions. Sorry for confusing you!